# Ajax image preview with jquery image cropper [blob url]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image

I'm trying to work with [this](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?2czyDOQ9) ajax image preview javascript snippet and the [cropper image](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?BEAlLLl9) jquery plugin to create a ajax preview cropper.

So far I got it so the preview of the image works and you can then click the preview and crop the image: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXmmEq?editors=101

The main problem I'm having is say you want to choose another image to crop. The old image that you previously picked remains there.

What I would like is:

1. To not have to click on the image to crop it and just be able to crop it immediately when it loads
2. Be able to preview another image and crop it if the user makes a mistake.

I figured for 2 you would just have to wrap the image cropper code in a function and do this:

```
function PreviewImage(no) {
var oFReader = new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage" + no).files[0]);
oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
  cropperCode(); // Wraps around image cropper code. Called when oFReader loads.
  document.getElementById("uploadPreview" + no).src = oFREvent.target.result;
};
```

**Edit**
I just noticed in the [cropper demo](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/) it has an upload icon near the bottom right of the image being cropped. When I hover over it says "Import image with Blob Urls"

I think this is the code:

```
    // Import image
var $inputImage = $('#inputImage');
var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var blobURL;

if (URL) {
  $inputImage.change(function () {
    var files = this.files;
    var file;

    if (!$image.data('cropper')) {
      return;
    }

    if (files && files.length) {
      file = files[0];

      if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type)) {
        blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        $image.one('built.cropper', function () {
          URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL); // Revoke when load complete
        }).cropper('reset').cropper('replace', blobURL);
        $inputImage.val('');
      } else {
        $body.tooltip('Please choose an image file.', 'warning');
      }
    }
  });
} else {
  $inputImage.parent().remove();
}
```

Here's [the new codepen try](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbGBxY)

Thanks for any help I might get.

Comment: first of all i wan to know that when will the image will croped.?? can you say that.?

Comment: Sorry Himesh, I'm not sure I understand? If you're asking when the image is cropped it's after you pick an image to upload. 

You can see in the codepen example I showed.

Comment: you haven't shown full code means where is the submit call or ajax call. >?

Comment: For the preview? 
This should be all of it:
http://pastie.org/10340951

You can try it on codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXmmEq?editors=101

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add another jquery library called [tooltip](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/tooltip).

The codepen used in the edit will work once library is added